# Zombie.js not playing nice with Backbone form submissions

Tags: backbone.js, bdd, zombie.js

Not sure if it's on my end or zombie.js's, but I cannot seem to get this very simple zombie.js  script to work on my Backbone app.  Is it something entirely on my end, or is it a known issue that zombie.js doesn't play well with Backbone apps?  I'm also using Pow (http://pow.cx/) to connect to the app through myapp.dev in case that is related.

Any advice or zombie.js examples with backbone would be extremely helpful!

```
Browser = require "zombie"
assert = require "assert"

browser = new Browser()
browser.visit "http://myapp.dev/", ->
  browser.clickLink ".sign-in a.route", ->

    browser.fill "email", "me@example.com" 
    browser.fill "password", "mypassword"

    browser.pressButton "input[type=submit]", ->
      #the html that is outputted is the exact same as before
      #the link is clicked, doesn't seem to be following through
      console.log browser.html(".sign-out a.route")
```

Comment: It would help to see the JavaScript posted rather that what looks like CoffeScript

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether you don't have any errors after `pressButton` call: `console.log(browser.errors)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no known issue with Zombie.js, Backbone.js, and/or Pow working together.  Most likely this is a bug on your end.  It would help to go step by step and see what is the first thing failing. For example, what happens when you just do:

```
Browser = require("zombie");
assert = require("assert"); 

browser = new Browser();
browser.visit("http://myapp.dev/", function() { console.log(browser.html()); });
```

That should go a log way toward pinpointing the problem.